# Fast way to keep one occurancy per element with numpy array and tuple

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

First question on Stack, hello everybody !

I have a tuple, with two 1D np matrix, from np.nonzero, for example :

`(array([479, 479, 479, 480, 480, 480, 481, 481, 481, 482, 482, 482, 650,
       650, 650, 651, 651, 651, 652, 652, 652, 653, 653, 653, 654, 654,
       654, 708, 708, 708, 709, 709, 709, 710, 710, 710, 711, 711, 711,
       712, 712, 712, 713, 713, 713], dtype=int64),
array([ 859,  860,  861,  859,  860,  861,  859,  860,  861,  859,  860,
        861, 1045, 1046, 1047, 1045, 1046, 1047, 1045, 1046, 1047, 1045,
       1046, 1047, 1045, 1046, 1047, 1039, 1040, 1041, 1039, 1040, 1041,
       1039, 1040, 1041, 1039, 1040, 1041, 1039, 1040, 1041, 1039, 1040,
       1041], dtype=int64))`

But in my future utilisation this tuple will be larger. I'm looking for the fastest way to keep only one occurancy of each element (the first) in the first column of the tuple, and keep its second coordonate from the second column. Plus, the first column is sorted

For my example, I would like this output :

`(array([479, 480, 481, 482, 650, 651, 652, 653, 654, 708, 709, 710, 711, 712], dtype=int64),
array([861, 861, 861, 861, 1047, 1047, 1047, 1047, 1047, 1041, 1041, 1041, 1041, 1041],dtype=int64))`

A naive solution could be :

```
for k in range(len(nozero[0])-1):
    i = nozero[0][k]
    i2 = nozero[0][k+1]
    j = nozero[1][k]
    j2 = nozero[1][k+1]

if  i != i2:
    x.append(i)
    y.append(j)
```

Feel free to suggest me anything about this, but also if you have a better idea to organize data ! (or if you want better explanations).

Thanks a lot !

Comment: keep its second coordinate from the second column, and array([861, 861, 861, 861, 1047, 1047, 1047, 1047, 1047, 1041, 1041, 1041, 1041, 1041],dtype=int64) is shown. It is not clear what you want to do with 2nd element of tuple. BTW tuple is immutable and you cannot change it. So you have to convert it to list first.

Comment: You should avoid the for. As you say, if your tuple will become bigger in the near future, a loop over all elements would be prohibitive. I would use numpy to accomplish part of the task

Comment: You should use a better example, or your data is always so regular. If you have always such a regular pattern, you could just generate the index of the first unique element with k = np.arange(0, len(nozeros[0]), 3), and then, x=nozero[0][k] and y =nozero[1][k].

Comment: Indeed I hadn't seen the regularity in my data, but they are not supposed to be that repetitive !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) on the first array to find a mask of all the first occurences. Then simply slice each array using the mask.

Note that `np.diff` results with an array of a size smaller by one than original, so we prepend a `1` (the first element in the array is always the first of its kind).

```
from numpy import array,int64
import numpy as np
arr1, arr2 = (array([479, 479, 479, 480, 480, 480, 481, 481, 481, 482, 482, 482, 650,
       650, 650, 651, 651, 651, 652, 652, 652, 653, 653, 653, 654, 654,
       654, 708, 708, 708, 709, 709, 709, 710, 710, 710, 711, 711, 711,
       712, 712, 712, 713, 713, 713], dtype=int64),
array([ 859,  860,  861,  859,  860,  861,  859,  860,  861,  859,  860,
        861, 1045, 1046, 1047, 1045, 1046, 1047, 1045, 1046, 1047, 1045,
       1046, 1047, 1045, 1046, 1047, 1039, 1040, 1041, 1039, 1040, 1041,
       1039, 1040, 1041, 1039, 1040, 1041, 1039, 1040, 1041, 1039, 1040,
       1041], dtype=int64))

first_occurences_mask = np.concatenate([[1], np.diff(arr1)], axis=0) > 0
first_occurences_mask
=> 
array([ True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,
        True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,
        True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,
        True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,
        True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)

res1, res2 = (arr1[first_occurences_mask], arr2[first_occurences_mask])
res1, res2
=> 
(array([479, 480, 481, 482, 650, 651, 652, 653, 654, 708, 709, 710, 711,
       712, 713]),
 array([ 859,  859,  859,  859, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1039, 1039,
       1039, 1039, 1039, 1039]))
```

---

(By the way, this is a very good first question. You've read the rules and best practices before you posted, and it shows.)

**EDIT (@alejandro) - Time Comparison**:

In order to prove that this method is faster than that of @B. M., below I did a comparison between both:

```
from numpy import array,int64
import numpy as np
import time

time1 = []
time2 = []

nelements = np.logspace(1,7)

for i in nelements:
    arr = np.random.randint(0,i, i)

    start = time.time()
    first_occurences_mask = np.concatenate([[1], np.diff(arr)], axis=0) > 0
    stop = time.time()
    time1.append(stop-start)

    start = time.time()
    np.unique(arr,return_index=True)
    stop = time.time()
    time2.append(stop-start)
```

which gives the following result:

[image]

This plot clearly shows that for big arrays the speed-up of using the concatenate is huge

Comment: Perfect, it's the fastest solution betwee yours and the one of B.M. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.unique`:

```
In [1]: i,j = nozeros  # your two arrays.
In [3]: uniq,index,count=np.unique(i,return_index=True,return_counts=True)
```

The unique elements og i are in `uniq`:

```
In [4]: uniq
Out[4]: 
array([479, 480, 481, 482, 650, 651, 652, 653, 654, 708, 709, 710, 711,
       712, 713], dtype=int64)
```

If you want the last corresponding elements in `j` as in your exemple :

```
In [5]: j[index+count-1]
Out[5]: 
array([ 861,  861,  861,  861, 1047, 1047, 1047, 1047, 1047, 1041, 1041,
       1041, 1041, 1041, 1041], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: I guess @Wogle220 needs the value of the element in the second column that correspond to the first occurrancy in the first column. If so, you should use y[ind]

Comment: Isn't `y[ind]` is what OP is after? also, +1 for using unique and return_index

Comment: It was not clearly written what output @Wogle220 wants.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough but this solution works, slower than the one of shx2, but works and returns what I wanted, so thanks a lot B. M.